# Default webpack configuration

Tags: webpack

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

> Out of the box, webpack won't require you to use a configuration file. However, it will assume the entry point of your project is src/index and will output the result in dist/main.js minified and optimized for production.

What loaders webpack include by default if no config is provided? What's the default configuration then?

The docs say that I don't need to use configuration but how can I know if default configuration will suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's defined [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js).

It can also be inspected via `node`:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
new webpack.WebpackOptionsDefaulter()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The documentation should be more explicit

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah, I couldn't find anything in the docs either :/